# GPG - all users see the keys

Tags: gnupg

How do I setup/configure gpg so that any person who uses the server that gpg is on can see the keys and run encryption?

I have already imported the pubring.gpg and set the trust level to 5 for our company's key, yet no other user can see the keys when they run gpg --list-keys.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want that all of your users can use that key for both encryption/decryption?

Answer (score 3):

GnuPG manages individual key rings ("GnuPG home directories") per system user. Furthermore, it is very picky regarding permission issues, so I'd not recommend sharing a keyring at all.

Options you have:

- linking the GnuPG home directory to all users (permission issues!)
- setting `$GNUPGHOME` to a shared folder (permission issues!)
- If you only deal with new users: add a GnuPG home directory already containing the key to the skeletons folder

  If you also deal with old users, you might loop through all users, `su` into them and import the key (can well be achieved using a script).
- Run a login script importing the (exported) company key or fetching it from a key server, and afterwards marking it as trusted.

I'd definitely prefer the last option, as it will prove most robust.

Given all of your users have their own OpenPGP key anyway, you might want to rely on the web of trust instead and make them sign your company's key (and sign their's in return). But whether this is a reasonable thing to do depends on what you want to achieve, and whether you want to generally deploy OpenPGP keys anyway.